# Count sets of increasing trend in a list

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, set, trend

I have to count the number of subsets where there is an increasing trend based on user input of the list and the length of the subset.

```
List:[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

k: The length of the trend.
```

for example...if k=3 and the data points increase for three consecutive numbers, then it is counted as one.

Here the input is the list and the length of the list and k

Example:

```
Input: List:{1,2,3,4,5,6}

 k=3

Output: 4. {(1,2,3),(2,3,4),(3,4,5),(4,5,6)}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following :

```
def group_by_trend(data, k):
    return [data[i*k :min((i+1)*k, len(data))] 
            for i in range(round((len(data)+1)/k))]

# test
k = 3
List = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

print(group_by_trend(List, k))
```

output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Comment: The output should be the number of sets. So in this case 3